# Generic JSON to convert any schema of given type to a common type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, jsonschema, jsonserializer

I've multiple web services using similar type of json requests as input. I need to have a common json 
   schema structure, which can fit any of the json requests.

Sample json schemas below:

```
Schema1 : 
{
  "param1": "string",
  "param2": "string",
  "param3": "string",
  "param4": [
{
  "p1": "string",
  "p2": "string",
  "p3": "string",
  "p4": "string",
  "p5": int,
  "p6": int,
  "p7": int,
  "p8": datetime,
  "p9": datetime
}
]
}
```

Schema 2:

```
   {
"param1": "string",
"param2": "string",
"param3": "srting"
"param4": [
    {
        "p1": datetime,
        "p2": "string",
        "p3": "string",
        "p4": "string",
        "p5": "string",
        "p6": int,
        "p7": [
            {
                "par1":datetime,
                "par2": "string",
                "par3": int
            },
            {
                "par1":datetime,
                "par2": "string",
                "par3": int
            },{
                "par1":datetime,
                "par2": "string",
                "par3": int
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
 }
```

Can I have a generic schema that can hold these 2 structures as shown above?

Comment: You can use `oneOf` or `anyOf` to have multiple subschemas.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Is this possible in JSON Schema? Yes. Is there any reason you think it wouldn't be possible? What have you tried so far? What leads you to your current understanding?

Comment: I wanted to have a generic schema that can hold these 2 requests, so that I can make it common for multiple APIs.

Comment: Oh, so your question is "How do I split up a schema to make it reusable"?